# "Segmentation fault" when accesing dynamically allocated struct members

Tags: c, struct, heap-memory

I have started to work on a program which implements a structure called "PhoneBook" having two members: "length" and "allocatedSpace", both of type "unsigned int". The structure is dynamically allocated. The two members of the structure are assigned in an external function called "InitializePhoneBook". Now, when I try to print the values of the two members of the structure inside the "main" function I get a "Segmentation fault" error.

PhoneBook.h

```
#ifndef PHONEBOOK_H
#define PHONEBOOK_H

struct PhoneBook
{   
    unsigned int length;
    unsigned int allocatedSpace;
};

void InitializePhoneBook(struct PhoneBook *phoneBook);
void ClearPhoneBook(struct PhoneBook *phoneBook);

#endif
```

PhoneBook.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "PhoneBook.h"

void InitializePhoneBook(struct PhoneBook *phoneBook)
{
    phoneBook = malloc(sizeof(struct PhoneBook) * 1);

    phoneBook->length = 0;
    phoneBook->allocatedSpace = 1000;
}

void ClearPhoneBook(struct PhoneBook *phoneBook)
{
    free(phoneBook);
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "PhoneBook.h"

int main(void)
{
    struct PhoneBook *phoneBook;

    InitializePhoneBook(phoneBook);

    printf("%d %d\n", phoneBook->length, phoneBook->allocatedSpace);

    ClearPhoneBook(phoneBook);

    return 0;
}
```

Running "./a.out" with "gdb" I get:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400621 in main () at ./main.c:12
12      printf("%u %u\n", phoneBook->length, phoneBook->allocatedSpace);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C is pass by value. Which means that the parameters are copied when calling a function. Your function `InitializePhoneBook()` will copy the non-initialised pointer, will assign to that copy the return value of `malloc()` and then forget that value when leaving the function. Your caller will continue with the un-initialized original.

Your function   `InitializePhoneBook()` can be changed in 2 ways:

```
struct PhoneBook *InitializePhoneBook(void)
{
    struct phoneBook *pb = malloc(sizeof(struct PhoneBook) * 1);

    pb->length = 0;
    pb->allocatedSpace = 1000;
    return pb;
}
```

or

```
void InitializePhoneBook(struct PhoneBook **pPhoneBook)
{
    *pPhoneBook = malloc(sizeof(struct PhoneBook) * 1);

    (*pPhoneBook)->length = 0;
    (*pPhoneBook)->allocatedSpace = 1000;
}
```

the call in main would have to be changed

```
struct PhoneBook *phoneBook = InitializePhoneBook();
```

or

```
struct PhoneBook *phoneBook;
InitializePhoneBook(&phoneBook);
```

respectively.

Comment: `struct PhoneBook *` should be the return type of your first function.

Answer (score 7):

When you do `malloc` in `InitializePhoneBook()`:

```
phoneBook = malloc(sizeof(struct PhoneBook) * 1);
```

It doesn't modify the pointer in `main` because the pointer you assign is local the function. Pass a pointer to pointer or rewrite the function return the `malloc`ed pointer.

```
void InitializePhoneBook(struct PhoneBook **phoneBook)
{
    *phoneBook = malloc(sizeof(struct PhoneBook) * 1);

    (*phoneBook)->length = 0;
    (*phoneBook)->allocatedSpace = 1000;
}
```

call in `main()`:

```
InitializePhoneBook(&phoneBook);
```

and change the prototype:

```
void InitializePhoneBook(struct PhoneBook **phoneBook);
```

Other issues I noticed:

- You should also check the result of `malloc` for failure.
- Use `%u` format specifier to print `unsigned int`s.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of the malloced pointer remains inside the InitializePhoneBook function.

For that you must return the pointer to the main so change the prototype to:

```
struct PhoneBook *InitializePhoneBook(struct PhoneBook *);
```

and the last statement of the above function should be:

```
return phoneBook;
```

and inside main call it this way:

```
phoneBook=InitializePhoneBook(phoneBook);
```